# Coldfusion server (apache httpd) is restarting frequently

Tags: apache, coldfusion, restart

We have Apache httpd server set up as our ColdFusion server on a Solaris box. And due to some code changes to the deployed ColdFusion application, our ColdFusion server (the httpd service and not the actual machine) is restarting frequently.

Any ideas on where to start looking? ...or which logs to turn to? ...or common culprits?

Comment: Can you clarify if it's the server physically power-cycling, or if it's just the httpd service restarting? Question title implies the latter, but question content implies the former.

Comment: Thanks, I've now clarified my question. I am referring to the httpd service restarting and not the actual machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the JVM logs, to see how often the garbage collector is being called.

It will most definitely have something to do with memory leaking on the new piece of code you've just deployed, so looking at the JVM logs, will give you a good clue.

Also, I'd suggest using a tool such as [FusionReactor](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/), as this will give you a great view of exactly which of your pages is doing, and how much memory each request uses.

Hope it helps